# EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() - This operation is not supported for non-relational platforms

Tags: mongodb, eclipselink, java-ee-6, nosql

I am working through the example from https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_6_and_nosql.

Here is a link to the model src http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/examples/org.eclipse.persistence.example.jpa.nosql.mongo/src/

The part that is causing me problems is:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory;
...
test.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mongo");
EntityManager em = test.factory.createEntityManager();
```

When org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager is invoked I get

```
SEVERE: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7108] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: This operation is not supported for non-relational platforms.
```

Here are all the dependencies I am using:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources" excluding="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.8/jersey-server-1.8.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.8/jersey-core-1.8.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.7.3/mongo-java-driver-2.7.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.nosql/2.4.0/org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.nosql-2.4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.0.4.v201112161009/javax.persistence-2.0.4.v201112161009.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/3.3.1.v201206041142/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-3.3.1.v201206041142.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr/3.2.0.v201206041011/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-3.2.0.v201206041011.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql/2.4.0/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.4.0/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.nosql/2.4.0/org.eclipse.persistence.nosql-2.4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/2.4.0/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.4.0.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Server is GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3. I can't figure out why createEntityManager would not be allowed, when I copied it all from example code that worked for others??

Comment: Can you provide more details, such as the exception stack trace if there is on and any difference you may have in your application from the first example.  Maybe post your persistence.xml, and be sure you also have logging turned on to catch any warnings that might indicate what is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception shows the EclipseLink build as 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600 while this feature requires EclipseLink 2.4 or later.  How ever you setup your dependencies, it seems to be using the EclipseLink version shipped with Glassfish.  You can try replacing/upgrading these bundles as described here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/updating_eclipselink_bundles_in_glassfish

Comment: I was picking up the glassfish jars.